# Eslint + typescript paths aliasing with craco Unable to resolve path to module '@SomeFolder/SomeComponent'

Tags: import, eslint, tsconfig, craco

can someone pls explain to me why I am still getting the error when I'm using

import SomeComponent from '@someFolder/SomeComponent';

```
this is my error
 Unable to resolve the path to module '@SomeFolder/SomeComponent'
```

this is part of my esLint

```
"settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "alias": {
        "map": [["@", "./src"], ["@someFolder", "./src/components/SomeFolder/*"]],
        "extensions": [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".jsx", ".json"]
      },
    }
  }
```

and this is part of my craco.config

```
  webpack: {
    alias: {
      '@convertor': path.resolve(__dirname, `src/convertors`),
      '@someFolder': path.resolve(__dirname, `src/components/SomeFolder`),
    },
  },
  jest: {
    configure: {
      moduleNameMapper: {
        '^@someFolder(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/components/SomeFolder',
      },
    },
  },  webpack: {
    alias: {
      '@convertor': path.resolve(__dirname, `src/convertors`),
      '@someFolder': path.resolve(__dirname, `src/components/SomeFolder`),
    },
  },
  jest: {
    configure: {
      moduleNameMapper: {
        '^@someFolder(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/components/SomeFolder',
      },
    },
  },
```

this is tsconfig.paths.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "@someFolder/*": [ "src/components/SomeFolder/*" ],
      "@convertor/*": [ "src/convertors/*" ],
    }
  }
}
```

this is full eslingrc

```
{
  "plugins": ["import"],
  "extends": [
    "airbnb-typescript-prettier",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "plugin:import/recommended",
    "plugin:import/typescript"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "no-param-reassign": ["error", {
      "props": true,
      "ignorePropertyModificationsFor": [
        "state"
      ]
    }],
    "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": 0,
    "@typescript-eslint/no-empty-function": 0,
    "@typescript-eslint/camelcase": 0,
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": "warn",
    "@typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment": "warn",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-shadow": "warn",
    "@typescript-eslint/ban-types": 0,
    "react/jsx-props-no-spreading": 0,
    "@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define": 0,
    "jsx-a11y/alt-text": 0,
    "max-classes-per-file": ["error", 10],
    "prettier/prettier": [
      "warn",
      {
        "endOfLine": "auto"
      }
    ],
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": [1, { "extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"] }],
    "react/prop-types": 0,
    "react/jsx-no-bind": 0,
    "react/destructuring-assignment": "warn",
    "react/require-default-props": "warn",
    "react/react-in-jsx-scope": 0,
    "react/button-has-type": 0,
    "react/no-array-index-key": "warn",
    "react/display-name": 0,
    "jsx-a11y/click-events-have-key-events": 0,
    "jsx-a11y/no-noninteractive-element-interactions": 0,
    "jsx-a11y/no-static-element-interactions": 0,
    "jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid": 0,
    "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": "warn",
    "radix": ["error", "as-needed"],
    "no-nested-ternary": "warn",
    "no-plusplus": 0,
    "import/prefer-default-export": 0,
    "import/order": "warn",
    "import/extensions": "warn",
    "import/no-cycle": 0,
    "consistent-return": 0,
    "camelcase": "warn",
    "guard-for-in": 0,
    "no-restricted-syntax": 0,
    "no-debugger": 1
  },
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["**/*.test.js", "**/*.test.jsx", "**/*.test.ts", "**/*.test.tsx"],
      "env": {
        "jest": true
      }
    }
  ],
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "alias": {
        "map": [["@", "./src"], ["@someFolder", "./src/components/SomeFolder/*"]],
        "extensions": [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".jsx", ".json"]
      },
      "node": {
        "paths": ["src"],
        "extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

PS pls don't suggest disabling `import/no-unresolved`. this isn't fixing problem it's just ignoring it